# How to customize number in Bootstrap 4 SVG date icon?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add a Bootstrap 4 SVG date icon but it defaults to the number 19. Is there any way to change the number 19 to something else, like 1, 2, 3 etc? Or display Sep 18 2020 (each word separate line) within the SVG?

If not, what is the use of this icon that is always showing number 19?

```html
<svg width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar-date" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1z" />
    <path d="M6.445 11.688V6.354h-.633A12.6 12.6 0 0 0 4.5 7.16v.695c.375-.257.969-.62 1.258-.777h.012v4.61h.675zm1.188-1.305c.047.64.594 1.406 1.703 1.406 1.258 0 2-1.066 2-2.871 0-1.934-.781-2.668-1.953-2.668-.926 0-1.797.672-1.797 1.809 0 1.16.824 1.77 1.676 1.77.746 0 1.23-.376 1.383-.79h.027c-.004 1.316-.461 2.164-1.305 2.164-.664 0-1.008-.45-1.05-.82h-.684zm2.953-2.317c0 .696-.559 1.18-1.184 1.18-.601 0-1.144-.383-1.144-1.2 0-.823.582-1.21 1.168-1.21.633 0 1.16.398 1.16 1.23z" />
</svg>
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/4fLj5xgh/

Comment: good luck editing the path .. I advise you to find something else because this SVG is not meant to be editable

Comment: You could just eliminate the number part of the SVG and use normal text instead

Comment: @j08691 can you please share an example? I tried `<text>20</text>` within the SVG but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can't because the number is displayed using a `path` (the second one in the svg):

```html
<svg width="3em" height="3em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar-date" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M6.445 11.688V6.354h-.633A12.6 12.6 0 0 0 4.5 7.16v.695c.375-.257.969-.62 1.258-.777h.012v4.61h.675zm1.188-1.305c.047.64.594 1.406 1.703 1.406 1.258 0 2-1.066 2-2.871 0-1.934-.781-2.668-1.953-2.668-.926 0-1.797.672-1.797 1.809 0 1.16.824 1.77 1.676 1.77.746 0 1.23-.376 1.383-.79h.027c-.004 1.316-.461 2.164-1.305 2.164-.664 0-1.008-.45-1.05-.82h-.684zm2.953-2.317c0 .696-.559 1.18-1.184 1.18-.601 0-1.144-.383-1.144-1.2 0-.823.582-1.21 1.168-1.21.633 0 1.16.398 1.16 1.23z" />
</svg>
```